# Update progress bar while writing files swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, ios10

I'm using swift 3 to write an iOS app. I'm trying to write a bunch of files in a loop and show progress in the UI. The loop goes:

1. write file
2. Check remaining disk space
3. Update UI and progress bar
4. Loop

The UI is not updating until the loop completely finishes. Funny enough, I update the UI with initial values FIRST THING in the ViewDidAppear function, before the loop even starts and that update doesn't even happen until after the loop finishes. Here is a code sample:

```
for _ in 0...100000 {
        let image = UIImage(name: "someimage_\(nameExt!).png")
        if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
            let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("myimage_\(nameExt!).png")
            nameExt! = nameExt! + 1
            try? data.write(to: filename)
        }

            let currentSpace = getSpace()
            progress?.progress = abs( Float((capacity!-currentSpace)/capacity!) )
            let progressValue = progress?.progress
            progressLabel?.text = "\(progressValue! * 100) %"
            spaceRemaining?.text = "free space: \(currentSpace/1000000) MB"
            print("free space: \(currentSpace/1000000000) GB")
            print("\(progressValue! * 100) %")
            print("----------")
}
```

Comment: UI updates only happen when the main thread is given time to process them.  Try moving your `for` loop onto a background thread and dispatching the changes to UI elements back to main.

Answer (score 0):

`UIProgressView`'s `progress` property is a float value between 0 and 1 by default. So if your progress is supposed to be at 50% then you'd need to set the progress property to 0.5.

When writing files you also need to make sure that your updating the progress view on the main queue. This may be why your UI isn't updating until the end.

```
var updatedProgress: Float = 0
// update progress

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    progressView.progress = updatedProgress
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I wrapped DispatchQueue.main.async{} around the update lines, and I'm having the same issue:


`DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.progressLabel?.text = "\(progressValue! * 100) %"
                    self.spaceRemaining?.text = "free space: \(currentSpace/1000000) MB"
                }`

Comment: Have you tried printing each value? Are you getting the values you expect? What are the values of your `progressValue` that you are multiplying by 100? What is the value of `currentSpace`?

Comment: If the whole `for` loop is already on the main thread, then simply adding `DispatchQueue.main.async` to update the progress bar won't do anything useful. That only works if the whole `for` loop is being run on a background thread.